Compute $\int_\gamma |z|^2\ dz$
Let $f(z)=|z|^2, \hspace{3pt} \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ and define $\gamma$ as the path given by the segment from $1$ to $1+i$ and the segment from $1+i$ to $i$ in the complex plane. Compute $\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz$.
My doubt is about the parametrization of $\gamma$.
My attempt is the following.
First, I defined
$$\gamma_1: \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \to \mathbb{C}, \hspace{3pt} t\mapsto 1+2it$$
$$\gamma_2: \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\to \mathbb{C}, \hspace{3pt} t\mapsto i+2(1-t)$$
and so:
$$\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}, \hspace{3pt} t \mapsto \begin{cases}\gamma_1(t), & 0\leq t\leq 1/2 \\ \gamma_2(t), & 1/2\leq t\leq 1\end{cases}$$
Therefore, I have that:
$$\int_\gamma |z|^2 \ dz=\int_{\gamma_1} |z|^2\ dz+ \int_{\gamma_2} |z|^2\ dz=$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} (1+4t^2)\cdot 2i\ dt+ \int^{1}_{\frac{1}{2}} \left(1+4(1-t)^2\right)\cdot (-2) \ dt=$$
$$=2i\Bigl[t+\frac{4t^3}{3}\Bigl]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}-2\Bigl[t-\frac{4}{3}(1-t)^3\Bigl]^1_{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{4}{3}(i-1)$$
Is the parametrization correct? Is my calculation of $\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz$ correct?

The result is right!

Perfect! Was there another smarter way to parametrize the $\gamma$ curve?

$\gamma_1(t)=1+it$ with $t$ from $0$  to $1$ and  $\gamma_2(t)=t+i$ with $t$ from $1$  to $0$ by computing $$\int_\gamma |z|^2\ dz=\int_{\gamma_1} |z|^2\ dz+\int_{\gamma_2} |z|^2\ dz.$$

Thank you very much!
